# where FILE structure is stored in a program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *openfile()
{
   FILE *fp1;     
   fp1 = fopen("test.c","r");
   return fp1;
}

int main()
{
    char c;
    FILE *fp;
    int a = 10;
    int b = 1000 - a;

    printf("Hello\n");

    fp = openfile();

    fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
    fclose(fp);

    printf("%c", c);
}
```

In the above program, i am opening a file descriptor in one function and passing it other function. This is working fine.

fp1 is declared locally to the function openfile(). since we are passing address, from the main function i could able to use the file pointer structure.

My question is where FILE structure is stored? And what would be the scope of the structure?

Answer (score 6):

It can be stored anywhere, that's up to the implementation of the runtime library.

Typically I would expect `fopen()` to do `malloc()`, i.e. allocate the `FILE` structure on the heap, but that's not a requirement. It could just as well dole out pre-allocated static structure instances for instance, if it's  designed to avoid heap allocations. It only needs to support `FOPEN_MAX` concurrent files (which must be at least 8).

Comment: I didn't know this, I just fixed my answer to leave a place for the possibitliy if it not being allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 5):

Normally it's allocated on the heap, and it's valid in any scope that has access to it until you call `fclose()` and it's not a file descriptor, it's a *stream*.

Also be careful and,

1. Always check that `fopen()` has returned a non-`NULL` pointer.
2. Always check the return value of `fscanf()`, even in this simple situation where you are using the `"%c"` specifier.